# Call AspNet API from React axios

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, axios

I have a AspNet controller that provides API. The Controller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public int Login(User user)
{ return 1; }

[HttpGet]
public SomethingHere GetSomething()
{ return new SomethingHere; }
```

Everything works fine with javascript calls using ajax:

```
function login() {
var credential = { nome: nome, password: password };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/APICalls/Login",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(credential),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (val) {
        if (val > 0)
           consol.log('User logged. Id = ' + val);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

I would like to call the same API in React using axios. I came up with the following:

```
function login() {
axios.post('/api/APICalls/Login', { nome: nome, password: password })
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Will it be enought to point to the same API or I'll have to edit the controller?

Comment: Why don't you try and see the result first?

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine. Just don't forget to configure your proxy in package.json.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I havent developed anything in react yet. Mine was just an idea and i wanted to know if I could use what I already have.

Comment: Question for both of you. In the ajax post I have to apply the `data: JSON.stringify(credential)`. Is this automatically done by axios or I have to do something to the parameter?